# Why is my Access database not getting updated?

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

This is my simple code for add new data in access database.

```
Dim i, sno As Integer
Dim sname As String
Dim rw As DataRow
'Add a new row to the Student table.
rw = DataSet11.Tables(0).NewRow
sno = InputBox("Enter the Roll no of the Student:")
sname = InputBox("Enter the Name of the Student:")
rw.Item("SNo") = sno
rw.Item("SName") = sname
Try
    DataSet11.Tables(0).Rows.Add(rw)
    'Update the Student table in the testdb database.
    i = OleDbDataAdapter1.Update(DataSet11)
Catch ex As Exception
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
End Try
'Displays number of rows updated. 
MessageBox.Show("no of rows updated=" & i)
```

When I run my application its work properly but when i restart my application database is not updated. why this happens?

Comment: Is the database in your solution or getting copied from somewhere? Every build will overwrite the one you updated.

Comment: Do you have your database file listed between the project files? If yes, what is the setting for the property _Copy to Output Directory_?

Comment: Read this to learn how to manage local data files: http://msdn2.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms246989(VS.80).aspx